# Laravel what exceptions or errors does update() return when it fails

Tags: laravel

Until now I used to write my update queries like this:

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('id', $id)->get();
$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';
$flight->save();
```

But if I understand it right this will do 2 queries. One select query then one update query.

So I decided to use laravels `update()` in order to only have 1 query.

eg:

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('id', $id)
->update(['name' => 'New Flight Name']);
```

But how can I check if $`flight` doesnt find anything bases on the id above, or if the `$flight` update fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `firstOrFail()` function

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('id', $id)
         ->firstOrFail()
         ->update(['name' => 'New Flight Name']);
```

or do a simple check

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('id', $id)->first();

if($flight) {
   $flight->update(['name' => 'New Flight Name']);
}
```